# Installing Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I have an issue. When I install Ubuntu, I burn it on a disk and boot it, the installer opens and everything is fine till I come to the installation location. There I can just see my hard disk name SATA.... but no drives. It just says Add Partion Tables or continue. When I click on Continue, there is an error. 'No root drive specified'. What should I do?

Comment: Can you add an image from disk management?

Answer (score 0):

You must creat a unallocated space in your hard disk  first.

I recommend create unallocated space By remove a windows drive in your windows 8 By right click on Computer in start and select manage 
and in disk management remove a drive.

and then  :

1. Click on unallocated space, click on new. Enter size as 10GB (you
   have to enter in mb), choose file system type as ext4, mount point
   /, partition type primary This means ubuntu root partition.
2. Click on unallocated space, click on new. Enter size as 2GB Or more, choose
       primary partition, file system type SWAP.
3. Click on unallocated space, click on new. Enter size 10GB or More if You need, choose
       , choose file system type as ext4, mount point
   /home . (If you don't creat this partition ubuntu locate /home in / and when you change your linux your user data like musics , document and your setting will be removed.if you creat /home you can keep this from format)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is obvious as u didn’t mentioned any root mount and swap area ..
At the time of installing Ubuntu you have to mention where all the files so called Ubuntu computer exist .. root means specifying "/" in the drive management after that it will be installed in any specified drive ..

it will be more easy to understand for you after attaching  screen shot so that i can navigate u simply...

But anyways you have to have to mention the following 
1.Root Partition by mentioning "/" at least 10 gigs or more.. depending upon ur free space.
2.Swap Partition either same as your ram or double of that ..
3.Home - this one is optional , it is the same as documents folder in windows . So after making it separate u can easily re-install Ubuntu in future without affecting Home ..hope this info cud help u.